# Create a tag if data exists in xquery

Tags: xslt, xquery

I am fairly new to Xquery. I am trying to achieve below scenario(xslt) which will create a tag based on a condition.

```
<xsl:if test="x = 0">
<Tag>Sample</Tag>
</xsl:if>
```

How to achieve the same in Xquery?

--Edited Below--

Tried with below code got the output as shown. What might have gone wrong?

```
<Root>   
<Name>sampleName</Name>    
     let $xyz := 10
   if ($xyz  > 1)
   then
   return <ns1:Primary_Acct_Num>11222</ns1:Primary_Acct_Num>
</Root>
```

Output(same as above input)

```
<Root>   
<Name>sampleName</Name>    
     let $xyz := 10
   if ($xyz  > 1)
   then
   return <ns1:Primary_Acct_Num>11222</ns1:Primary_Acct_Num>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
if (x = 0) then <Tag>Sample</Tag> else ()
```

As for using the expression inside of a direct element constructor, you need to enclose it in curly braces https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#dt-enclosed-expression, as in

```
<Root>   
<Name>sampleName</Name>
{
   let $xyz := 10
   return
       if ($xyz  > 1)
       then <Primary_Acct_Num>11222</Primary_Acct_Num>
       else ()
}
</Root>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv88

A different approach would be to create the element but add the condition in a predicate with e.g.

```
<Root>   
<Name>sampleName</Name>
{
   let $xyz := 10
   return <Primary_Acct_Num>11222</Primary_Acct_Num>[$xyz > 100]
}
</Root>
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv88/1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where to add this? It throws error if used as below after the root element.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some context as to which input you have and where you want to output the `Tag` element.

Comment: Thanks Martin for looking into this.Added the xquery code tried in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. It worked when curly braces are used.